# Android com.google.android.c2dm for use in IntentFilter not found

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, intentfilter

I have a broadcast receiver that gets pushes. The intents this receiver gets contain the action com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE.
I want to implement a second receiver that is registered and unregistered in my Activities so I can detect if my app is running and throw an alert instead of an notification. I figured I would have to register this second receiver with the same action in its IntentFilter like

```
MyReceiver myReceiver = new MyReceiver();
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE);
MyActivity.this.registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
```

Android Studio claims c2dm can't be found. I know its deprecated, but shouldn't it still be there? The plan is to have this two receivers for this action and give this one a higher priority than the one thats registered in my manifest. Is this approach ok and if so, whats my problem?

Comment: Deprecated means it will be removed sometimes. Maybe this happened now in your release of Google libs...

Comment: Of course, but this pushes come straight from googles GCM Demo Server Java Application. The implementation of the first receiver is pretty much exactly from Googles tutorial. So if this intents contains this action I thought it was unlikely that they really removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I overlooked the fact that IntentFilter takes a String. I need to put it in quotes like

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE");
```